# GCC cannot find stdio.h with OS X even though command line tools is installed

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, compilation, osx-yosemite

I'm using OS X 10.10.4 and am having trouble compiling .c files. Most help I've found on this issue suggests installing Xcode's command line tools however, trying to do so gives

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I used the find option to locate stdio.h

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app -name stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
```

So clearly there are several locations with it.

I tried adding the '-v' flag while compiling to try and get more insight and saw that it wasn't searching very thoroughly.

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Russian Owl, if you do code by indenting four spaces rather than backticks, it solves your octothorpe problem - I've adjusted your text to do this. To do it fast for a big block, just mark all the text and use CTRL-K. If only I could help you with the actual question :-)

Comment: Helpful tip anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all default compiler on OSX is `clang` instead of `gcc`
  So better to use `clang`
- If you have to use `gcc`you may set headers search path by compilation option `-I option` ( **example:** gcc `-Ipath_to_headers yourprogram.c -o yourprogram` )

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I honestly thought I had been using gcc this whole time but clang worked immediately.